# using variables to add datatable column in jsquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am new to jquery.
I am trying to  pass the column data/names as variable from  an array.  The column assignment is not working. The commented section works, but the variable assignment to columns field does not. Can somebody help? Following is the snippet:

```html
    <html>
<head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      
      </head>
        <body>
          <script>
            
            var dataSet = [
            ["Tiger Nixon1", "10", "20", "51", "300"],
            ["Tiger Nixon2", "10", "20", "51", "300"],
            ["Tiger Nixon3", "10", "20", "51", "300"]
    ];       

    $(document).ready(function() {
              
       var  colname1= [
          { title: "Name" },
                     { title: "column1" },
                    { title: "column2" },
                    { title: "column3" },
                    { title: "column4" }];

          var i = 2;

          function myFunc1(item, index, arr) {
                arr[index].title = item;
                value2.innerHTML = colname1[index].title;
                        }
   /*-----------not working--------------------*/
           var t = $('#example').DataTable({
                data: dataSet,
                columns: colname1.forEach(myFunc1, i)
            });

   /*-----------working--------------------*/

            
              /* var t = $('#example').DataTable({
                    data: dataSet,
                    columns: [
                    { title: "Name" },
                    { title: "column1" },
                    { title: "column2" },
                    { title: "column3" },
                    { title: "column4" }]
                });*/
             
              
    });

              
              
              
    </script>
          
               <div > <span> this is test text</span> </div>
           
             <div class="content"> <span id="value1"> this is test2 section</span> </div>
             <div class="content"> <span id="value2"> this is test3 section</span> </div>



             <div>
                 <table width="300" class="display" id="example"></table>
             </div>

          </body>
        </html>
```

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Did you click on the blue `Run code snippet` button? Do you see that you have syntax error there?

Comment: It is showing script error when I am passing column variable using a function. It is not specifically telling me the error.

Comment: It how a script error because you have a syntax error. First fix the syntax error you got there.

Comment: I edited and added commented section that I want to modify. Appreciate your help in advance. The commented section works fine

Comment: I still see syntax errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITi3Y.png

Comment: 1. The `forEach` function should receive an element from your array. What are you trying to do there? 2. The `columns` of the `DataTable` should be an array, but the use of `forEach` function doesn't return an array.

Comment: Instead of individually itemizing the columns, I want to pass loop /each base assignment. The data the datatable will get will may have variable column numbers passed as row arrays.

Comment: The `columns` value should be an array. so if you do `columns: thisIsSomeFunction()` - the `thisIsSomeFunction` function should return an Array.